# datetime format conversion from mm-dd-yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using asp net core with entity framework. I have a `datetimepicker` which i am using as calendar. I have customize its format using jquery like this.

```
  $('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'       
    });
```

This shows the date forma to user.
and then converting it to C# datetime I am saving it in database in same format.Every thing is correct till now.
Now on my next visit this page has to be pre-filled if data is there. This time on the textbox of calendar it is showing some thing like `0007/02/19`  where as the date that i entered is `1993/07/02` and the date that is saved in database is `7/2/1993`. I tried using

```
            String DateString = Convert.ToString(ProfileDetails.DateOfBirth);
            IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

            DateTime dateVal = DateTime.ParseExact(DateString, "MM/dd/YYYY", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(dateVal);
            user.DateOfBirth = dateVal;
```

this but was getting error string is not in valid datetime format. In my modal I have defined date as datetime. I am not getting the solution. Can any one gives me the correct way to complete that.

Comment: Your post is rather confusing. You convert a date to a string in your first line of code but then do a bunch of other stuff that I don't quite follow. Can you explain what the further four lines of code are for?

Comment: @Chris I too don't understand that code but i just fixed and posted an answer. Sometimes better don't ask

Comment: @J.Doe: Except that your analysis falls flat as I've now indicated on a comment on your answer. I think it is quite plausible that the first line is generating a DateString like "07/02/1993" but because the date picker expects stuff in `yyyy-mm-dd` format it probably tries to be clever and parses the date as `yyyy = 07, mm = 02, dd = 19`. This is why knowing what the other code is there for would be very useful and why the OP should also make it clear how they are passing the data to the datepicker or the textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuz you are using `MM/dd/YYYY` instead `MM/dd/yyyy`

Working code:

```
String DateString = Convert.ToString("07/02/1993");
IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
DateTime dateVal = DateTime.ParseExact(DateString, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: I don't understand this code. `ProfileDetails.DateOfBirth` in the original code must be a DateTime or else there is no point calling `Convert.ToString`. Your second line is not needed since you never use the culture. The line you have changed from YYYY to yyyy is potentially useful but almost certainly not the cause of the problem since having YYYY will actually cause that line to throw a `FormatException` unless the given date looks like "07/02/YYYY" which I very much doubt it is.

Comment: This is only "repaired" @Rishabh code from question. No more, no less

Comment: My point is that while it might correct a mistake it is almost certainly not actually going to solve the user's problem and thus isn't really an answer to the question.